# Dynamically change an html id value for a navigation menu

Tags: javascript, html

I got a template which frames every page with a header and a footer.
The navigation is part of it.

The problem is:

For the current tab to be highlighted, the id must be id="current"

So it looks like this:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#" id="current">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Discuss</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Buy</a></li>
</ul>
```

In this situation Home is highlighted, and the rest is not.

When I click on "Discuss", 2 things happen.

1) The related php page is called
2) It should be highlighted!

What would be the best way to do that? 
Do I have to call a javascript function able to clean the id value and change it to another dom? But the dom is set with the id!

Is there any other ways?

I'm a bit lost on the best way to achieve that.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to change the ID. What you want to have is a *class* named current you add to the tab:

```
<ul class="navigation">
 <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Discuss</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Buy</a></li>
</ul>
```

I recommend using jQuery. Then you can bind a function like this:

```
$("ul.navigation li").click(function() {
  // load page
  ...code here...
  // set tab
  $("ul.navigation li.current").removeClass("current");
  $(this).addClass("current");
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. This looks like the best way possible. I can have a javascript function in the template page which is then triggered on any list element and the class would be updated.

Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

First, you could dynamically add the id to the correct element via your server side code (i.e. PHP, .NET, whatever you're using).

But that way, you're kind of misusing an ID. You should probably just change your CSS rules to apply the highlighting to an element with a class of `current`, rather than an id. Then, you can apply the class via your server side code, or on the client side with Javascript.